# Asp.net core mvc parsing wrong string value to <script> using Base64

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, pdf, pdf.js

I have an application where you can upload and view images and i am trying to implement pdf's aswell without using a free trial or an expensive package.

*The application works by:*

1. uploading file
2. decoding file (IFileFormat) to bytes
3. putting the bytes into a database
4. taking the bytes from the database
5. converting bytes to base64
6. creating a link and viewing the image(works). or using pdf.js to paint the pdf as an image on canvas

**the controller code:**

```
            string imageDataBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(image.FileData);
            ViewBag.basesixtyfour = imageDataBytes;
            Console.WriteLine(imageDatabytes);
```

**the script code:**

```
<script>
    console.log('@ViewBag.basesixtyfour');
</script>
```

in short the console writeline gives me a string value that is **275,500 bytes**.

the console.log gives me a string value that is **308,050 bytes**.

I have tried using a model to carry the string aswell but the same problem arises.
So the question is, *why does this happen? are there any workarounds?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Figured it out after a while.*

***Had to serialize for json and then deserialize using Newsoft.Json***

**controller**

```
ViewBag.story = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imageDataBytes);
```

**View**

```
var pdfData = atob('@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ViewBag.story))');
```